# Ember API response returns token in meta data. How to retrieve this meta token value using ember data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I've model called "customer" which returns personal details of customer in below structure. It also returns token in meta data. How to retrieve this from model?

```
"customer" : {
    "title" : "Mr",
    "firstName": "Person",
    "surname" : "surname",
    "primaryTelephoneNumber" : {
        "number" : "0123456789",
        "type": "Home"
    }
},
"meta" : {
   "token" : "6e16063a-8a89-5d1a-b9cb-72d14c4c7579"
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with metadataFor ? var meta = this.store.metadataFor("customer");

Comment: This works..Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the metadata just use the metadataFor method, so in your case it would be `var meta = this.store.metadataFor("customer");`